# getting TypeError when calling object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a checkers game and am running into a TypeError when trying to create rules for the game. here is the code:

```
var tryAgain = function(){

  return {
    pcolor : function() {
      position1 = prompt("chose either 'wht' or 'red'");
      //attemptMove(getMove(position1,position2).startRow, getMove(position1,position2).startCol, getMove(position1,position2).endRow, getMove(position1,position2).endCol);
    },
    invalid : function() {
      position2 = prompt("Can't move there, try again");
      attemptMove(getMove(position1,position2).startRow, getMove(position1,position2).startCol, getMove(position1,position2).endRow, getMove(position1,position2).endCol);
    }
  };  
}

var attemptMove = function(row1, col1, row2, col2)
{
  if(board[row1][col1] != 'wht' || board[row1][col1] != 'red'){
    tryAgain.pcolor();
  }

  if(board[row2][col2] != ' X '){
    tryAgain.invalid();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't create the "tryAgain" object i believe you should be using `tryAgain().pcolor()`

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/6rrt40n0/1/)

if you are looking for "tryAgain" to be an object and not a function try this fiddle:

[Object JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/6rrt40n0/3/)

Note i removed `function() {` and the `return {` from the tryAgain

Comment: Well that worked, but I don't quite understand why??? Am I not calling the method on the object? Why does TryAgain() need to be called again?

Comment: Updated answer and don't forget to mark the answer correct if you deem it so.